# Query to find duplicate and duplicate with value

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
 select (a.rowindx) rowindx, (b.rowindx) rowindx1 
 from dedupinitial a,
     dedupinitial b 
 where a.rowindx < b.rowindx 
 and a.poivalue = b.poivalue 
 order by a.rowindx;
```

This query gives me results like

```
rowindx rowindx1 
945 88715
945 91674
945 90947
945 91013
88715   91674
88715   90947
88715   91013
```

But I want result like:

```
rowindx rowindx1 

    945 88715
    945 91674
    945 90947
    945 91013
```

What is the query fot that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a min(first column), and a group by (second column)

```
select min(a.rowindx)rowindx, b.rowindx rowindx1 
from dedupinitial a,
dedupinitial b 
where a.rowindx < b.rowindx --and a.rowindx 
 and a.poivalue = b.poivalue 
group by b.rowindx
order by 1;
```

PS: I don't understood the *and a.rowindx* part

Comment: that was mistake i have update the same But Your query not working gives not a GROUP BY expression error